# JavaScript trigger does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to trigger a button so when user loads a page, the button is automatically clicked.

My code is following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  console.log("it's here");

  $("#btnPeriod").trigger('click');
});

$("#btnPeriod").on('click', function(){
  var ahhhhh = "<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>";
  ahhhhh = ahhhhh.replace(/&#32;/g, " ");
  console.log(ahhhhh);

  $.extend($("#noticeList").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),{
    filters : JSON.stringify({
      groupOp : "OR",
      rules : [{
        field : "notiWriter",
        op : "eq",
        data : ahhhhh
      }],
      groups : []
    })
  });
  $("#noticeList").jqGrid("setGridParam", {search : true}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current : true, page : 1}]);
});
```

and when the page is loaded, I can see log of "it's here" and value of ahhhhh.  However, even though I can see log, the action suppose to be happened does not get applied.  Funny thing is when I click the button, then it works, with another log message of variable ahhhhh.

FYI, I am using jqGrid and when I click btnPeriod button, it filters rows that its cellvalue of notiWriter does not match with variable ahhhhh.

For now, when I load this page, it displays like following:
[image]

And then, when I click a button, it only shows certain rows like following:
[image]

And I hope it always look like second picture when a user loads the page.

I once used setTimeout, but it turned out it did not work well, so I hope you give me some help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: move all code inside document ready

Comment: It's not. When your JavaScript is executed the document is already ready, and thus the trigger is called before the listener is attached. This explains why it does work when you manually click, but does not work when you simply load the page.

Comment: Please don't remove comments... now mine doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: That's a viable theory.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the click handler to the button inside the document.ready handler, and before you call `trigger()`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#btnPeriod").on('click', function(){
        var ahhhhh = "<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>";
        ahhhhh = ahhhhh.replace(/&#32;/g, " ");
        console.log(ahhhhh);

        $.extend($("#noticeList").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),{
            filters : JSON.stringify({
                groupOp : "OR",
                rules : [{
                    field : "notiWriter",
                    op : "eq",
                    data : ahhhhh
                }],
                groups : []
            })
        });

        $("#noticeList").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
            search: true
        }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ 
            current: true, 
            page: 1
        }]);
    });

    $("#btnPeriod").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: If that were the problem, clicking the button manually wouldn't work either, right? (It makes sense to do anyway -- if he's going to use `ready` at all -- but it doesn't seem to fit the described symptoms.)

Comment: [Stephan has a theory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411780/javascript-trigger-does-not-work#comment56564736_34411780) which might explain the symptom (the document is *already* ready, and so jQuery does it's surprising "call the handler synchronously" behavior). If so, while this would work, it might make more sense to just remove `ready`.

Comment: I did this before, and it did not work.  I just did it again just in case, and still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the event binding inside the jquery `ready` function and bind the event before trigger the click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   console.log("it's here");


   $("#btnPeriod").on('click', function(){
        var ahhhhh = "<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>";
        ahhhhh = ahhhhh.replace(/&#32;/g, " ");
        console.log(ahhhhh);

        $.extend($("#noticeList").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),{
            filters : JSON.stringify({
                groupOp : "OR",
                rules : [{
                   field : "notiWriter",
                   op : "eq",
                   data : ahhhhh
                 }],
                 groups : []
                })
             });
           $("#noticeList").jqGrid("setGridParam", {search : true}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current : true, page : 1}]);
      });

    $("#btnPeriod").trigger('click');

 });
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Rory's answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: posted within 2 minutes from one another, with the code in this answer closer to the code in the original question than the other answer. Convergent answers, it happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes. And when it does, and I find I've come after, I delete.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Sure, but that's not a reason for moderators to do so. I see now it wasn't you who flagged the post in this case however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Indeed. It frankly never occurred to me to do so. I wasn't suggesting nefarious intent, which (rightly or wrongly) I'd have to believe to flag it for mod attention.

Answer (score 0):

Why not including the click event binding inside your ready function ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
console.log("it's here");

$("#btnPeriod").on('click', function() {
    var ahhhhh = "<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>";
    ahhhhh = ahhhhh.replace(/&#32;/g, " ");
    console.log(ahhhhh);

    $.extend($("#noticeList").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"), {
        filters : JSON.stringify({
            groupOp : "OR",
            rules : [{
                field : "notiWriter",
                op : "eq",
                data : ahhhhh
            }],
            groups : []
        })
    });
    $("#noticeList").jqGrid("setGridParam", {search : true}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current : true, page : 1}]);
});

$("#btnPeriod").trigger('click');
```

});